# Binding Variadic Functions C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a function like this:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
void sum(int start, T... next);
```

And I wanted to bind this. How would I do this?

---

To be more precise, if the function had a fixed amount of arguments, it would look something like:

```cpp
void sum(int start, int next); // function signature

// ...

auto binded_sum = std::bind(sum, 0, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Now how would I 'placehold' a variable amount of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth mentioning that C++20 also provides [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) for exactly this purpose:

```cpp
auto bound_sum = std::bind_front(sum, 0);
```

(This has a number of potential advantages over the naïve lambda implementation; see the [paper proposing the feature](https://wg21.link/p0356) for details if you are so concerned.)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for! Also, is this `bind_front` more performant than the lambda?

Comment: @Coder100 Usually should be similar, for properly written lambdas. For example, `std::bind_front` will automatically forward the parameters, so when used with expensive/large types it can be more efficient than a lambda that takes by value. However, you can also write a lambda to handle this case properly: it's just more work on the part of the author.

Comment: ah, I see. Unfortunately, this is a C++20 feature, and it appears Visual Studio doesn't support it, do you have any resources for implementing this?

Comment: @Coder100 It's not entirely trivial to implement, but e.g. [abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/functional/bind_front.h) has an implementation that you can look at. That said, according to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog#vs-2019-165) MSVC should support `std::bind_front` since 16.5—make sure you're using at least that version and compiling with `/std:c++latest` to get C++20 support. If that's too onerous then just using a lambda is probably a better fit :)

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```
auto binded_sum = [](auto... next) { sum(0, next...); };
```

Comment: how did I not think of that? Thank you so much!

Comment: I will mark the answer as correct in ten minutes, its making me go on cooldown because of the rapid answer lol